# Sending messages from the database to Kafka with the guaranty of not losing them and keeping the order

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I need to send data from database to `Kafka`. Any data should not be lost and the message order should be strictly kept as they are fetched from the database. After the messages are sent, I need to remove them from the database. Once completed, this task will be repeated again and again (it is scheduled via `@Scheduler`).

I have come to the conclusion that the guaranty of not losing any message and keeping the order of them requires the following: before sending a new message, I need to make sure that the previous one was successfully delivered to the Kafka broker (`Acks=all`, `min.insync.replicas=2`). If a message is not delivered to the broker, there is no point to send the next one. As a result, the solution turns out to be synchronous. Here is my code example:

```
public List<String> sendMessages(String topicName, List<Object> data) {
    List<String> successIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object value : data) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> listenableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, value.getSiebelId(), value);
        try {
            listenableFuture.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("todo");
            break;
        }
        successIds.add(value.getId());
    }
    return successIds;
}
```

`successIds` contains the id of messages which are successfully delivered to the broker. Next, I use them to delete the corresponding data in the database. If during the operation of sending messages from the `List<Object>` data some message was not delivered to the broker for some reason, then we end the iteration earlier and delete exactly what managed to get into `successIds`. In the next iteration, we will start with those messages that were not included in the `successIds`, because they have not been removed from the database.

From this solution requires the rejection of asynchrony, which will certainly lead to a decrease in the performance. I already tested it and it works very slowly. I am new to `Kafka` so would like an expert opinion. Is this solution optimal?

Comment: Hello, one observation is that this code may send messages more than once: if the system crashes after it has sent a bunch of messages, but before taking note of the `successIds` and committing the transaction with the DB. Make sure the receiver of these messages can handle duplicates!!!

Comment: You are righ. But the system is idempotent, so dublicates are allowed, it is ok.

Comment: Idempotent, good! Then, you may want to look at the "message to self pattern". This way you do not delete the db records synchronously. Just iterate over them and send those messages to Kafka. **BUT** add a different consumer that consumes the same messages sent by the code in the question; this consumer will be responsible to delete the records from the DB.

Comment: Well, that sound good to have a separate consumer to delete messages from the db. Though if that consumer read the messages from kafka, how those messages will be read by a real consumer for business logic? 
In general, I look for a solution without extra consumer, if possible.

Comment: Hehe, Kafka topics are not queues! Each message is persistent (for the configured time) and is available to all the consumer groups. Just make sure the consumer that deletes from the DB is in a different consumer group than the one executing the rest of your logic. Consumer group id is a simple string!

Comment: (This is actually a pattern for implementing event-driven systems; one component publishes a message, e.g. "user created", and possibly many observers consume it and do their own thing - one observer may create the user's home folder in the file system, another send a notification email, another initialize user's DB structures etc)

Comment: Nikos, thx, for showing this direction to me. I will need some time to learn this appoach.

Comment: I'm new to kafka, but manuals say you should configure `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to 1 to keep ordering, it looks like in that case you can wait for `SendResult`  asynchronously as in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution below give me much faster productivity (~ 100 times on my test data) comparing with `listenableFuture.get` posted in the question. Here I add a `callback` to `listenableFuture` where in `onSuccess` method I put the successfully sent ids into the list. After the iteration over the list, I call `flush()` on `kafkaTemplate`.

```
@Override
public List<String> sendMessages(String topicName, List<T> data) {
    List<String> successIds = new ArrayList<>();
    data.forEach(value ->
            kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, value.getSiebelId(), value)
                    .addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Object> result) {
                            successIds.add(value.getId());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {
                            log.warn("todo");
                        }
                    }));
    kafkaTemplate.flush();
    return successIds;
}
```

The output with `successIds` of this solution however might differ from the one in the question. Say, I have 5 messages to send. If 3th message is not delivered (say due to problem with the network), the 4th, 5th will still be sent to the broker and might be delivered (if the network problem is fixed). So `successIds={1,2,4,5}`. Later on `3th` messages will be sent with a new list iteration and therefore might be delivered after `5th` message. So it delivers faster, give the guaranty that no message is lost, but will not give 100% guaranty of keeping the order. This is not ideal, but maybe I will try to use it as a compromise.

In the same situation, the solution with `listenableFuture.get` will not even send 4th, 5th messages, and gets `successIds={1,2}`. Not delivered messages `3th, 4th, 5th` will be sent in the proper order in a new list iteration.

I could not explain properly why I gain much productivity with the presented solution. I guess `kafkaTemplate.flush()` somehow do asych stuff, while `listenableFuture.get` put the request in the sequence to wait the corresponding responses.

P.S. Interesting to note, that if I use the same code but remove line `kafkaTemplate.flush()` and instead I initialize bean `kafkaTemplate` with `autoflash=true`, then it works again slowly.